# Pycaret installtion error on Windows VM (AWS)

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, pycaret

I have been trying to install pycaret (ML library in python) on windows vm hosted on aws.

This library installs all the pre requisite libraries for doing ML such as numpy, pandas, sklearn, etc, etc.

However, when I am trying to install it on Windows VM (AWS), I am getting an error saying "error in the below packages: numpy".

I tried reinstalling and updating numpy but that also didnt work.

Is there anyone who is aware of why this is happening or any experience with pycaret installation on a windows virtual machine would be really helpful.

Thanks

Sincerely,
Rajat

Answer (score 1):

Its being discussed here

https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/2381

on the official pycaret community.